# How do I add a timeseries plot to a regular plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I made a moving average of my timeseries and I'd like to super-impose it on top of my timeseries.

Here's my series `ggplot(daily_revenue, aes(day, revenue)) + geom_line()`

[image]

Here's my moving average `ma(ts(daily_rev_full$revenue, start = c(2014, 1), frequency = 365), order = 15) %>% autoplot()`

[image]

I tried to add them together by including them as separate `geom_line` values. I also tried to add autoplot to ggplot and I tried to create a regular plot and then add the moving average with `lines()`.

Comment: If you use XTS, you can get most of such functionality with little effort https://joshuaulrich.github.io/xts/plotting_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TTR** can be used to generate the moving average more effectively in this case.

As an example, suppose 100 random numbers are generated, and a 30-period simple moving average is generated.

```
numbers<-rnorm(100)

#SMA
library("TTR")
simplemovingaverage<-SMA(numbers,n=30)
plot(numbers,type='l',col='blue',xlab="X",ylab="Y")
lines(simplemovingaverage,type='l',col='red')
title("Numbers")
```

Using plot to plot the actual values, and lines to plot the SMA, here is the plot that is generated:

[image: sma]

Answer (score 0):

Using the `forecast` package you can generate a plot of time series objects using `autoplot()`. In order to superimpose your moving average you can use the `autolayer()` function. See below reprex.

```r
library(forecast)

autoplot(WWWusage) +
  autolayer(ma(WWWusage, order = 10), colour = TRUE)
#> Warning: Removed 10 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>